# How To Create and Backup a Bootable System Image of Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: server, backup

**Objective**:

- I am trying to back up my unmanaged VPS to remote cloud storage
  (Google Drive or Storj) by creating a system image so that if my VPS is wiped in a disastrous event. I can restore everything in minutes without typing dozens of command lines to set up Ubuntu again, then my web hosting panel, hardening the system, etc. Ideally, it would also have daily backups of the latest changes to my VPS hosting.
- I have Cyberpanel and WordPress backed up daily to remote storage, but I would like the OS to be backed up as well.
- I am not trying to back up individual files and folders. I am trying to back up an entire system to get it back up and running as fast as possible if the entire server gets wiped.
- I am new to Linux, so please hold my hand like a three-year-old. Thanks!

**My Setup**:

- Unmanaged VPS
- Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
- Cyberpanel
- WordPress Site
- Google Drive
- Storj

Comment: Does your hosting provider have this capability? Mine does, but it costs extra.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Unfortunately not. They don't have any backup options.